# how to do second step of two way sms communication architecture of IBM Worklight

Tags: android, sms, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

In two way sms communication architecture,the second step is "SMS messages are sent from mobile devices to the SMS Gateway". How to achieve this from mobile device. I need to this on android.

Answer (score 0):

The Two-Way SMS Communication overview is described in the [Worklight documentation](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_enabling_SMS2way_communication.html) and a more detailed description of the architecture is in the [Two-way SMS Communication](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_06_Two_way_SMS_communication.pdf) getting started, which also includes a [code sample](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/SMS2WayProject.zip).

The second step of the architecture (sending SMS message from device to server) is done through the intermediation of a [SMS Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) that should be configured accordingly to forward specific SMS messages to the Worklight Server through the Receive SMS Servlet.

I haven't tested it myself, but you could potentially use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway) or [this other app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.addhen.smssync) to turn an Android device (with phone/SMS plan) into a SMS gateway to receive and route SMS messages to Worklight.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks eabe for response. . Can you post some code for doing this...I have done configuration in SMSConfig.xml .But I wanted to know how to send request from    mobile I mean which Api of worklight should be used for this

Comment: Perhaps you are not picturing the functionality in its entirety. Two-Way SMS is designed to allow featured phones (and/or smartphones) to interact with your backend without an app or even internet access. Let's say your end user sends an SMS to your gateway with the message "Knock-Knock". Using the Two-Way SMS feature you can have your adapter process the message and respond to the device with an SMS message. So there is no API's to call on the mobile device, just simple SMS messages.